# Use ? at end of url without the need for pagename.ext

Tags: url, .htaccess, web, url-rewriting

On my website I pass parameters like this:

http://www.mysite.com/somepage.php?action=something

But I would like do just do this:

http://mysite.com/?action=something

How can I do this? Do you know of any good, simple resources around? I can't find any because I don't know exactly what to look for.

Lots of thanks in advance!

jase

Comment: I assume you are using Apache, if so use mod_rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I am using http://www.winhost.com/ - They do Windows-based hosting, but also provide PHP support on all their plans etc.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you show will usually go to the index file in the root directory (e.g. `index.php`).

You will be able to catch `$_GET["action"]` from there without any additional work.

Comment: Oh, hmm. Okay, awesome. Is that browser specific, or some kinda server thing that does that? :) and Thanks!

Comment: @Lucifer the latter. It's the reason why requests for `www.example.com` go to `www.example.com/index.html` (or whatever your index file is)

Comment: Ah! Sweet - I will accept when the timer runs out :) Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /somepage.php?action=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Haha! That's awesome, thank yoouuuuu :D - I'm gonna go read up on .htaccess, it looks pretty cool!

Comment: This isn't quite the rewrite he's looking for (based on the question). You're constructing the query from the path, but in the question the input URL has a query string too.

Comment: @Laurence, I thought that's what the $1 was for?

Comment: @Lucifer: In the above the $1 is getting the query string from the path. eg: http://example.com/something turns into http://example.com/somepage.php?action=something. Maybe you're happy with that, I'm just pointing out that it isn't what your question actually asked for. It is possible to do what you asked for with .htaccess as well, you'd just need a different RewriteRule.

Comment: @Laurence; Ah, I get it. Thanks for pointing that out and explaining, :) - I ended up writing a rewrite rule myself after reading some tutorials on HTAccess. I'll post the solution soon